# Django Celery ConnectionError: Too many heartbeats missed

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, django-celery

## Question

How can I solve the `ConnectionError: Too many heartbeats missed` from Celery?

### Example Error

```
[2013-02-11 15:15:38,513: ERROR/MainProcess] Error in timer: ConnectionError('Too many heartbeats missed', None, None, None, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 97, in apply_entry
    entry()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 51, in __call__
    return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 153, in _reschedules
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 265, in heartbeat_check
    return self.transport.heartbeat_check(self.connection, rate=rate)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 134, in heartbeat_check
    return connection.heartbeat_tick(rate=rate)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 837, in heartbeat_tick
    raise ConnectionError('Too many heartbeats missed')
ConnectionError: Too many heartbeats missed
```

### App Overview

- Django app using celery for periodic background tasks
- Hosted on Heroku
- Single task scheduled to run every 15 minutes via settings / celerybeat
- Messaging handled via CloudAMQP add-on
- Processes run by

  - `web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --workers=2 --worker-class=gevent someapp.wsgi:application`
  - `scheduler: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py celery worker -B -E --maxtasksperchild=1000 --loglevel=WARNING`

### Package Versions

Just what I think are relevant:

```
Django==1.4.3
amqp==1.0.8
billiard==2.7.3.20
celery==3.0.14
gevent==0.13.8
greenlet==0.4.0
kombu==2.5.6
raven==3.1.10
```

### What I've Tried So Far

- Correlating error with activities (doesn't seem to correlate with user's visiting app, background tasks being called, app idling)
- Googling / searching SO until my fingers were numb
- Upgrading packages to latest versions
- Various levels of logging
- Exception capturing with Sentry (doesn't appear in sentry)
- Cannot reproduce error locally under development environment, only in production on Heroku

### Possible Relevant Info

- I'm not sure exactly when this error first appeared (~ one month ago?)
- May be related in some way to the following changes (don't recall error before this, not 100% sure though)

  - `celery==3.0.13` to `celery==3.0.14`
  - `amqplib` -> `amqp`
  - `kombu==2.4.8` to `kombu==2.5.4`
- Error only appears in logs (doesn't get picked up by New Relic or getsentry.com)

Comment: We have the same issue. But sad to say until now there is no solution :(

Comment: The answer below solved it for me. Try setting `BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 0`. Good luck!

Comment: We've been seeing this error with a very similar heroku setup as you.  I wonder if anyone has reported to CloudAMQP?  Regardless, I haven't seen any actual problems from it so i basically ignore it.

Comment: I have not reported it to CloudAMQP. I thought the issue was with `celery` or `amqp` not their service (I could very well be wrong here). Unfortunately, these errors made my CloudAMQP usage skyrocket. Perhaps I have a less than ideal setup somehow.

Comment: Yeah i just switched my broker to Redis, so I can use the same broker and results backend, and have had good success with this.

Comment: Funny you mention this, just switched to redis a week ago. So far, not a single error from background tasks. Plus, it can serve double duty as a cache store. Wish I made the switch sooner.

Comment: @Jeff yeah once i realized there's no real advantage of memcached over Redis for my usage I switched cache over too.

Comment: I added a bug for this on github.com: https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/issues/37 . I'm not sure if it'll get fixed but I did post a work-around using Python 3 + asyncio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How often does it happen?

It may be that the heartbeat monitoring is not working properly in your case.
The heartbeat support was introduced fairly recently, so there may be bugs.
I cannot reproduce this here, so I need more data to understand what is going on.

You can disable heartbeats by setting `BROKER_HEARTBEAT=0`.
If this is a bug then the worker should run fine, but it will not be able
to quickly detect a broken connection.  Being unable to detect connection loss is only
a problem in some environments (usually caused by specific router/firewall configurations)

Comment: How often: strangely variable; 20 minutes to two hours between errors. I've set `BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 0` and will report back. Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: After setting `BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 0` and waiting 24 hours, I have not seen this error again. I'm not sure how / why this error was happening, but this stopped it from occurring. Thanks!

Comment: @asksol, When you say "Being unable to detect connection loss is only a problem in some environments", does that mean it's ok to disable the heartbeat safely? I've been having the exact same problem. I run celery 3.0.11 on my laptop and I don't see the issue. We run 3.0.12 on our servers and we see this issue there.

Comment: You can safely disable it.  The only thing that will happen if the broker cannot detect connection loss is that it will take a longer time for messages to be released back and redelivered, but there will be no data loss.